# Get site name to create a dynamic URL

Tags: 2010

I would like to know if there is a way to get the Site Name to somehow create a dynamic url within a content editor webpart.

For example if I have the following absolute url:

```
http://myserver/mysitecollection/mysite/documentlibrary/allitems.aspx
```

I would like to build a dynamic url where mysite is automatically populated based on the site I'm in.

```
http://myserver/mysitecollection/{SiteNameVariable}/documentlibrary/allitems.aspx
```

Thanks in advance,
Jovi

Comment: Hey, same type of question i guess: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33507/relative-url-for-html-links-in-site-template/33535#33535